# How to set ini file attributes during an Inno install

Tags: inno-setup

Can we set file permission for an ini file using inno setup?
At the time of instalation, i need to write some values to a ini file and then set the permision to read only. And during uninstalation, I need to read the file and change the permision to write mode and write some data to ini file and then again i need to set the permission to read only. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why do you need the ini file to be read-only? If you intend to write to it, then it's more appropriate for it to be read-write, otherwise it's misleading.

Comment: No. Actually after instalation of the application, i need no one to make any changes to it. So for that reason, i need to make it read only after writing some contents to the file

Comment: But a user who wants to write to it can simply remove the read-only flag from the properties dialog. If he doesn't own the file (i.e. is limited user while the app is in Program Files), then he can't write to it anyway, read only flag or not. What I mean is this isn't real security, if the user is intent on writing to the file he can.

Comment: k. Then can you suggest me a better approach for doing this thing. Iam facing a big problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the file permissions in `[Code]`, maybe using the `BeforeInstall` and `AfterInstall` parameters of the `[Ini]` entry. The attributes can be set using the Windows [`SetFileAttributes()`](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=SetFileAttributes_%28%29) API function.

Comment: but can i write to the ini file and then hide it by using SetFileAttributes()?

Comment: Yes, using the suggestions I just made. We will not do your work for you.