# Setting up an icon for start menu folder group in InnoSetup

Tags: menu, inno-setup, pascalscript

To my surprise I did not find the solution how to set up an icon for the start menu application group folder laying ahead. I am looking for the automatic solution in InnoSetup script.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like a bit of an odd thing to ask for, since (a) most apps don't customize their Start-menu folder icon, so yours would look very out of place, and (b) with Windows 7's program pinning and Start-menu searching, hardly anyone will go digging through All Programs to see the folder in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the `desktop.ini` file with the content like this if you want to use the `*.ico` as a resource (where `c:\somepath\icon.ico` is path to your icon):

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=c:\somepath\icon.ico,0
```

Or create the `desktop.ini` file with the content like this if you want to use the icon from the executable as a resource (where `c:\somepath\program.exe` is path to your executable):

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=c:\somepath\program.exe,0
```

Save this `desktop.ini` file into the directory where you want to apply the icon. One very important note, you have to set to this newly created file attributes ***Hidden*** and ***System***, otherwise it won't work!

So please check very carefully if the InnoSetup won't clear these attributes if you'll have the file included in your setup package while installing.

Comment: +1 I didn't realized that this is what the OP wanted. if yes you could use the `[ini]` section to generate that file.

Comment: also you could use `PathMakeSystemFolder` api to make it system folder. `desktop.ini` will automatically be set to proper attributes.

Comment: @kobik, thanks! I've just described what is needed to change the icon InnoSetup independent. About the `[ini]` section you're right, I'll include [`the implementation`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8339866/960757) later on ;)

Comment: @kobik, not that easy as I thought; you have to notify shell about the changes, and `SHChangeNotify` what was my first candidate has pointer parameters. The closest function for this, the `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings`, which can create the `desktop.ini` file is more complicated and much more easier might be to put it into my favorite external library.

Comment: and `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings` does not make the folder system as I mentioned?

Comment: also, you can pass pointer parameters. simply declare them as `PChar`: `procedure SHChangeNotify(wEventId: Longint; uFlags: UINT; dwItem1, dwItem2: PChar); external 'SHChangeNotify@shell32.dll stdcall'`. passing `''` as `nil`. Here is an excellent [example](http://www.sandon.it/?q=node/9).

Comment: Actually I found that not only does "SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings" w/FCS_FORCEWRITE create the necessary desktop.ini, it will also set the target folder with the necessary system flag to. Beats having to make a bunch of WritePrivateProfileString(), etc., calls to do the same thing, and the function will set things up properly for you.  
Maybe kobik you were doing it wrong.  
It's a bit tricky on how the "pszIconFile" path field works. You have to set a MAX_PATH buffer to it your self.  
To make sure you have it right try it first with a read of an existing ini first with FCS_READ et al.

Comment: Can someone post an example on how to do that with the InnoSetup script?